# Function that takes a list and returns value?

Tags: python, list

Write a function slice() that takes a list and start and end values and returns the slice of the list?

This isn't HW, but something that the course teacher said we should do over the weekend, isn't it as simple as this? What the teacher showed us was something different though..

```
def slice (l, start, end):
    x = l[start:end]
    return x
```

Comment: Your approach seems correct.  Note however that it will return a *copy* of the slice.  If you modify it, the original list will be unaffected.  This might or might not be what is needed.

Comment: you want to slice a list with start-end values ? I dont understand what you want excatly.

Comment: I don't find any question here.

Comment: I mean, the `list[start:end]` notation is called slice notation, so that's probably what you want.  Keep in mind that that does NOT include the end'th element, so if you had a list from 0-9, and you did [2:8], you would end up with [2,3,4,5,6,7].  Also, behavior is undefined if `l` is not a list, or if `start`, `end` are outside the bounds of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your teacher wanted the function to take the indexes and not values?

If it's indexes, your solution is right.

If it's values, a quick and dirty way would be to this:

```
def slice(alist, start, end):
    s = alist.index(start)
    e = alist.index(end)
    return alist[s:e+1]
```

You can add the check for inputs, and also modify the function if you don't want the greedy approach, as the index function returns the index of the first element it can find in the list starting from left (which mightn't be what you want for the end value).

Comment: this is what i thought might be the real question

Comment: @jamylak: yeah, but I am not sure why the question was downvoted though... Even with this answer, the OP will have something to work on at the end... :)

Comment: Thanks, I think this might be it.

Answer (score 0):

here is some different methods to do it:

```
>>> def return_slice(l,start,end):
...     return l[slice(start,end)]
... 
>>> return_slice([1,2,3,4,5,6],2,5)
[3, 4, 5]

>>> def return_slice(l,start,end):
...     return l[start:end]
... 
>>> return_slice([1,2,3,4,5,6],2,5)
[3, 4, 5]

>>> import itertools
>>> def return_slice(l,start,end):
...     return list(itertools.islice(l,start,end))
... 
>>> return_slice([1,2,3,4,5,6],2,5)
[3, 4, 5]

>>> import operator
>>> def return_slice(l,start,end):
...     return operator.getitem(l,slice(start,end))
... 
>>> return_slice([1,2,3,4,5,6],2,5)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: While we're here you forgot `operator.getitem(l, slice(start, end))`

Comment: yeaaa, let me add it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get very close slice behavior using range and a list comprehension:

```
return [l[x] for x in range(start, end)]
```

That doesn't handle negative index values properly.

In truth, Python programs that want to emulate classes don't have to write functions.  There's a special method name `getitem` that is called to perform [] indexing and it will receive a slice object that will assist in decoding the slice into start, stop and step values for a range.  You can read more about that in chapter 3 ("Data Model") of the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html)